# (36)File name too long: Cannot map GET while masking URL for feed setting plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, url-rewriting

I've referred most of the similar questions on stack and various other forums but was not able to get the right answer to the error. In my WP site I want to mask my feed player URL but as the GET parameters are 8 it gives me the above error. I tried to search the file request.c to apply patch given on https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45187 , for my server but could not find the file. I am using a Linux server.

Answer (score 0):

“try this instead”.
Please use $_POST method because $_GET have some memory